# getting the value of checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to get the value of checked checkBoxes but the problem is that they will be dynamic on my web page eg :

```
while ($row=myqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo"<div>";
    echo"<select id=\"course\" onchange=getCheckBox()>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    </select>";
    echo"<div id=\"checkBoxArea\">";
    echo"<buttton id=\"w\" >w</button></div>";
}
```

the ajax call `getCheckBok()` will get the result from a server and but it on checkBoxArea the result will look like this :

```
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"aaa\" class=\"stdcheckbox\">";
echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" value=\"bbb\" class=\"stdcheckbox\">";
```

when pressing on button w I need to get the value of the checked checkbox how can I do this ?

I have tried this jQuery code :

```
var x=$(this).parent().find(".stdCheckBox").value;
```

Comment: do you have any js code to show?

Comment: you mean the getCheckBox() code ?

Comment: I meant your try to do what you want .. Ok ya pop just wait

Comment: var x=$(this).parent().find(".stdCheckBox").value;

Comment: considering that the button w and the checkboxes on the same div and the class of checkboxes is .stdCheckBox()

Comment: ok try this http://jsfiddle.net/wp5vch3L/1/ .. I hope it will help .. dont forget to include jquery

Comment: Good Luck ya Ahmed  :)

Answer (score 2):

*Vanilla JavaScript* solution to create an *Array* of the *values* of *checked* `<input type="checkbox"/>`s

```
function checked_values(node) {
    var checked;
    if (!node) node = document;
    checked = node.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
    return Array.prototype.map.call(checked, function (e) {return e.value;});
}
```

```js
    function checked_values(node) {
        var checked;
        if (!node) node = document;
        checked = node.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
        return Array.prototype.map.call(checked, function (e) {return e.value;});
    }
window.addEventListener('load', function () {
    document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log(checked_values());
    });
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" value="a"/>a</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="b"/>b</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="c"/>c</label><br/>
<label><input type="checkbox" value="d"/>d</label><br/>
<button>Test (console)</button>
```